# InnoDB High history list length grows indefinitely

Tags: mariadb, innodb

I have MariaDB 10.11.5 slave on quite busy system (40k QPS, 50% UPDATES, slave replication ROW based).
For some reason History list length cannot catch up with running transactions:

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` shows:

```
Trx id counter 409514244518
Purge done for trx's n:o < 409513788919 undo n:o < 0 state: running
History list length 391120222
```

History list length is 391M but only 455k transactions are not purged. Not purged transactions are between 200k-600k, but history list length grows almost indefinitely. `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` show no transactions active for longer than 10seconds.
BP Data dirty <20%, BP Data 80%

Server has ~30% CPU usage on 128cores, 50% ram usage (of 1TB total) and no more than 100MB/s IO read/write on NVMe storage so there are a lot of spare resources.

Some important values from my.cnf:

```
sync_binlog = 1000
slave_parallel_workers = 32
slave_parallel_mode = optimistic

innodb_log_file_size=32G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

innodb_max_purge_lag = 1000000
innodb_max_purge_lag_delay = 10
innodb_purge_batch_size = 1000
innodb_undo_tablespaces = 8

innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm = 50
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384G
innodb_io_capacity = 10000
innodb_io_capacity_max = 20000
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_fill_factor = 80
innodb_flushing_avg_loops = 100
innodb_log_compressed_pages = OFF
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_purge_threads = 64
```

When i do STOP SLAVE and ProxySQL drop slave from pool, then History length quickly reduces to 0. But what can i do to force MariaDB to reduce History list length without stopping traffic? Server still has a lot of space resources.

Answer (score 0):

The following may avoid the problem:

If the UPDATEs are on "like" or "upvote" counters, remove the column from the main table.  Instead, have a separate table with the counter; `JOIN` by `thing_id` when you need to see all the info.

If that is not your situation, please elaborate.

Comment: No, this is a client database with approximately 250 tables and various workloads. I have limited ability to modify the queries/workload. Instead, I'm trying to figure out why a server with plenty of spare physical resources (CPU/RAM/NVMe IO) is not able to keep up with the transaction history. I have comprehensive monitoring in place with Percona PMM, yet I've been unable to identify any bottlenecks.

Comment: 10 seconds is terribly long for a transactions; any longer than 2 seconds?

Comment: Logs show that client is making ~5 queries per minute that took ~8seconds each. 99.9% of remaining queries took less than 1second and are not logged. These 8sec queries are select involving some inefficient joins across 3 tables, 10-15M records each. But they are only 5 SELECTs per minute and should not affect transactions history that much. But dropping traffic completely from slave results in transaction history to start reducing within few seconds.

Comment: Let's see those 8-sec queries, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`.